# .Net Core 3.1 Web Api AWS Lambda, Upload file to S3 - Broked File Result

Tags: c#, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, .net-core-3.1

I have create a Web Api project in C# using AWS Lampda.
The Api using to upload media file to S3 bucket => SNS on upload terminate.

I tryed the code in localhost and all right, the files was uploaded in S3 bucket and. Its readable..

I production mode, the lamda work with only pdf or txt file, the *png,jpeg,zip,etc* file is broken. Ive noted that the size of file is double for *png,jpeg,zip*. I dont know why.

```
public UploadResponse UploadFile(UploadRequest request)
        {
            AmazonS3Client client = new AmazonS3Client(Settings.GetAppKey(), Settings.GetSecretKey(), 
                RegionEndpoint.GetBySystemName(request.RegionS3));
            if (request.File.Length > 0)
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(request.FileName))
                {
                    request.FileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                }
                MemoryStream inputFile = new MemoryStream();
                using (inputFile)
                {
                    request.File.CopyTo(inputFile);
                    var d = request.File.ContentType;
                    var s = request.File.Length;
                    var uploadRequest = new TransferUtilityUploadRequest
                    {
                        InputStream = inputFile,
                        ContentType = request.File.ContentType,
                        Key = request.FileName,
                        BucketName = request.BucketName,
                        CannedACL = S3CannedACL.PublicRead
                    };
                    TransferUtility fileTransferToS3 = new TransferUtility(client);
                    fileTransferToS3.UploadAsync(uploadRequest).Wait();
                };
            }
            return UploadResponse.CreateUploadResponse(request.File.ContentType, request.FileName);
        }



        protected override void Init(IWebHostBuilder builder)
        {
            RegisterResponseContentEncodingForContentType("multipart/form-data", ResponseContentEncoding.Base64);
            builder
                .UseStartup<Startup>();
        }
```

Comment: The solution is set multipart/form-data into api gateway settings..

Comment: Can you help me to fix the same problem ?

Comment: Hi, yes sure! If you have the same problem, you should set the 'multipart /form-data' value inside binary-media-type of your method api gateway response.